# 3 Jpanel in JFrame, my button is not visible

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` with three `JPanel` objects. I have a problem with two of the panels. I can see in my frame, the panel `JPanelProduit` with object but for the panel, `JPanelInformations` and `JPanelVentes`, I see nothing. Where is my error?

### My Code

```
package IHM;

import javax.swing.*;

import Donnees.Categories;
import Donnees.CategoriesCellRenderer;
import Donnees.CategoriesListModel;
import Donnees.Marques;
import Donnees.MarquesCellRenderer;
import Donnees.MarquesListModel;
import Donnees.Produits;
import Donnees.ProduitsCellRenderer;
import Donnees.ProduitsListModel;
import Fabriques.FabCategories;
import Fabriques.FabMarques;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
 
public class Fenetre {
    
static Connection conn;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:BDD/bdd","sa","");

        FabCategories.getInstance().demarrerConnexion(conn);
        FabMarques.getInstance().demarrerConnexion(conn);
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Gestion des Produits");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,3, 3));
 
        JPanelProduit jPanelProduit = new JPanelProduit();
        JPanelInformations jPanelInformations = new JPanelInformations();
        JPanelVentes jPanelVentes = new JPanelVentes();
        
        jPanelProduit.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        jPanelProduit.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        jPanelVentes.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        
        f.add(jPanelProduit);
        f.add(jPanelInformations);
        f.add(jPanelVentes);
        f.setSize(700,700);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
 
class JPanelProduit extends JPanel {
     
    public JPanelProduit() throws SQLException {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,5,5));
        
        String labelCat = "Categories";
        String labelMark = "Marques";    
        String labelProd = "Produits"; 
        
        JList<Categories> listCategories= new JList<Categories> ();
        JList<Marques> listMarques= new JList<Marques> ();
        JList<Produits> listProduits= new JList<Produits> ();
        
        JScrollPane listCategoriesScrollPane = new JScrollPane (listCategories);        
        
        add(new JLabel(labelCat));
        add(new JScrollPane(listCategoriesScrollPane));
        listCategories.setCellRenderer(new CategoriesCellRenderer());;
        listCategories.setModel(new CategoriesListModel());
        
        add(new JLabel(labelMark));
        JScrollPane listMarquesScrollPane = new JScrollPane (listMarques);        
        add(new JScrollPane(listMarquesScrollPane));
        listMarques.setCellRenderer(new MarquesCellRenderer());
        listMarques.setModel(new MarquesListModel());
        
        add(new JLabel(labelProd));
        JScrollPane listProduitScrollPane = new JScrollPane (listProduits);        
        add(new JScrollPane(listProduitScrollPane));
        //listProduits.setCellRenderer(new ProduitsCellRenderer());
        //listProduits.setModel(new ProduitsListModel());
        
    }
}
 
class JPanelInformations extends JPanel {
  
    public JPanelInformations() {
        JPanel PanelInformation = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1,5,5)); 
        
        JLabel labelInfo = new JLabel ("INFORMATION");
        JLabel labelPrix = new JLabel ("Prix");
        JLabel labelDesc = new JLabel ("Description");    
        JLabel labelQuant = new JLabel ("Quantite");    
        JTextField fieldPrix = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextArea fieldDesc = new JTextArea (20, 20); 
        JTextField fieldQuantite = new JTextField (20); 
            
        PanelInformation.add(labelInfo);
        PanelInformation.add(labelPrix);
        PanelInformation.add(fieldPrix);
        PanelInformation.add(labelDesc);
        PanelInformation.add(fieldDesc);
        PanelInformation.add(labelQuant);
        PanelInformation.add(fieldQuantite);
    }
}

class JPanelVentes extends JPanel {
         
    public JPanelVentes() {
        JPanel PanelVentes = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        JLabel labelVendre = new JLabel ("VENDRE");
        JLabel labelQte = new JLabel ("Quantite");
        JLabel labelPromo = new JLabel ("Promotion");
        JLabel labelTot = new JLabel ("Total");    
        JTextField fieldQte = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextField fieldPromoEuros = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextField fieldPromoPourcent = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextField fieldTotal = new JTextField (20); 
        
        
        PanelVentes.add (labelVendre);
        PanelVentes.add (labelQte);
        PanelVentes.add (fieldQte);
        PanelVentes.add (labelPromo);
        PanelVentes.add (fieldPromoEuros);
        PanelVentes.add (fieldPromoPourcent);
        PanelVentes.add (labelTot);
        PanelVentes.add (fieldTotal);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a screen shot of the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use JavaFX? Its (in my opinion) easier to use.

Comment: replace this f.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,3, 3)); with this : f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,3, 3));

Comment: try the code change below in my changed answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this:

```
public JPanelInformations() {
    //JPanel PanelInformation = new JPanel(); remove new instance of panel
    setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1,5,5)); 

    JLabel labelInfo = new JLabel ("INFORMATION");
    JLabel labelPrix = new JLabel ("Prix");
    JLabel labelDesc = new JLabel ("Description");    
    JLabel labelQuant = new JLabel ("Quantite");    
    JTextField fieldPrix = new JTextField (20); 
    JTextArea fieldDesc = new JTextArea (20, 20); 
    JTextField fieldQuantite = new JTextField (20); 

    add(labelInfo); //remove PanelInformation.
    add(labelPrix);//remove PanelInformation.
    add(fieldPrix);//remove PanelInformation.
    add(labelDesc);//remove PanelInformation.
    add(fieldDesc);//remove PanelInformation.
    add(labelQuant);//remove PanelInformation.
    add(fieldQuantite);//remove PanelInformation.
}
```

AND

```
public JPanelVentes() {
    //JPanel PanelVentes = new JPanel(); remove the new instance of JPanel
    setLayout(new GridLayout());
    JLabel labelVendre = new JLabel ("VENDRE");
    JLabel labelQte = new JLabel ("Quantite");
    JLabel labelPromo = new JLabel ("Promotion");
    JLabel labelTot = new JLabel ("Total");    
    JTextField fieldQte = new JTextField (20); 
    JTextField fieldPromoEuros = new JTextField (20); 
    JTextField fieldPromoPourcent = new JTextField (20); 
    JTextField fieldTotal = new JTextField (20); 


    add (labelVendre); //remove PanelVentes
    add (labelQte);//remove PanelVentes
    add (fieldQte);//remove PanelVentes
    add (labelPromo);//remove PanelVentes
    add (fieldPromoEuros);//remove PanelVentes
    add (fieldPromoPourcent);//remove PanelVentes
    add (labelTot);//remove PanelVentes
    add (fieldTotal);//remove PanelVentes
}
```

Comment: I use your advice but but nothing has changed

Answer (score 4):

The JPanelInformations in the constructor creates a local instance `JPanel PanelInformation = new JPanel();` which is not added to main panel.

You should either add it to `this` or get rid of it at all and add all the labels to `this` directly.

The same with JPanelVentes

Answer (score 1):

Inside `JPanelInformations` class you are creating new JPanel class `PanelInformation` and adding other elements in it. You should just call `add()` as `JPanelInformations` already extends JPanel and you are creating instance of `JPanelVentes` class.

So follow same JPanel logic you have used in `JPanelProduit` class.

Same goes for `JPanelVentes` as well.

Also take care of naming conventions. Makes life easy

```
JPanel panelVentes = new JPanel();
```

Comment: you have correctly posted the actual solution to this problem. Thanks a lot.